# ListView no AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

Meu código não carrega os dados para list view quando ta dentro do `AsyncTask`, mas se for colocado no `onCreateView` funciona perfeitamente.

```
public class Tab_os_Fechadas extends Fragment {

    private String url ="http://redeml.no-ip.info/controleos/mobile/list_os_fechadas.php";
    private String parametros ="";
    private  ListView listOSFechadas;
    private int i;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


       View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_os_fechada,null);

        new SolicitarDados().execute(url);
        return x;

    }

    private  class SolicitarDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String > {


        View view;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return ConexaoDB.postDados(urls[0], parametros);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            try {
                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                }


                ArrayList<ItemOSFechadas> listaFechada = new ArrayList<ItemOSFechadas>();

                ItemOSFechadas a = new ItemOSFechadas("g1","ffff");
                ItemOSFechadas b = new ItemOSFechadas("g1","ffff");
                ItemOSFechadas c = new ItemOSFechadas("g1","ffff");
                ItemOSFechadas d = new ItemOSFechadas("g1","ffff");
                listaFechada.add(a);
                listaFechada.add(b);
                listaFechada.add(c);
                listaFechada.add(d);

                ListAdapterOSFechadas adapterOSFechadas = new ListAdapterOSFechadas(getContext(),listaFechada);
                listOSFechadas = (ListView)view.findViewById(listFechadasOS);
                listOSFechadas.setAdapter(adapterOSFechadas);
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Minha intenção é fazer meu retorno JSON e montar todo meu list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não posso executar seu código por isso não tenho certeza, mas acho que seu problema esta relacionado com seu id de sua ListView.

```
listOSFechadas = (ListView)view.findViewById(listFechadasOS);
```

Não entendo o porque de **listFechadasOs**
como id, já que não existe nenhum integer(int) com este valor.

Há também algums erros com o **View**.
Tente editar seu código da seguinte forma:

```
//Criando variável view
private View view;
//Remova sua LitView da AsyncTask e defina em onCreateView.
@Override public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_os_fechada,null);
       listOSFechadas = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.id_da_listview);
       new SolicitarDados().execute(url);
       }
       return view; 
 }
```

Comment: Tentei dessa forma e não deu certo.. a minha listview não aparece os dados que crio, a minha função SolicitaDados é exeucutada normalmente, mas nao mosta os dados da listview

Comment: conseguir acertar, e ta funcionando ok , mas fui testar no celular e o listview nao carregou, mas no emulador do android studio carregou, como posso identificar o problema ?

Comment: E bem difícil te dizer somente olhando para este pedaço de código. Tente enviar seu projeto para o github e forneça o link para que eu possa tentar identificar seu problema.